# 'Make: exec: compile: not found' Guile's Haunt build error (CentOS 8; Guile 2.0.14; Haunt 0.2.4)

Tags: makefile, build, compilation, exec, guile

The build of 'Haunt' ('make' step) fails with the following:

```
GEN      haunt/config.go
./pre-inst-env: line 31: exec: compile: not found
```

'compile: not found' ?

Guile is in version 2.0.14, Haunt 0.2.4, the mothership CentOS of version 8. The guile-devel package is present. Any ideas?

~~Ps. Should it be theoretically possible to 'make' it on another x86_64 machine, transfer the files and 'make install' inside of the target environment?~~

Comment: Never mind, ditched CentOS 8, installed Debian 10, problem '*solved*'. 10 > 8. Ps. Unsuprisingly not possible to 'make' on one and 'make install' on another.

Comment: Actually, I have the same issue on Lubuntu 18.04 and I sort of hoped that an answer would be here. (=

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue on Lubuntu 18.04. Here's a hack that has worked for me.

A bit of googling lead me to re-check the output of `configure`:

```
$ ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
configure: checking for guile 2.2
configure: found guile 2.2
checking for guile-2.2... /usr/bin/guile-2.2
checking for Guile version >= 2.2... 2.2.3
checking for guild-2.2... no
checking for guile-config-2.2... no
checking for guile-tools-2.2... no
checking if (system reader) is available... no
checking if (commonmark) is available... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating example/Makefile
config.status: creating website/Makefile
config.status: creating haunt/config.scm
config.status: creating pre-inst-env
config.status: creating test-env
config.status: creating scripts/haunt
```

The `no` on lines 14--16 of output seem to be a problem: for whatever reason those packages are not found by `configure`. However, I could manually set the variables that `Makefile` uses (after using `dpkg` to locate the things):

```
$ export GUILD=/usr/bin/guild
$ export GUILE_CONFIG=/usr/bin
$ ./configure
(...)
checking for guild-2.2... /usr/bin/guild
checking for guile-config-2.2... /usr/bin
(...)
```

Now `make` has worked, as did `make install`, although the latter required `sudo` in my case. In any case, I am not yet happy with the solution, because the example from the [website](https://dthompson.us/projects/haunt.html) (in particular the `haunt build`) does not work yet.

**EDIT:** On Lubuntu 20.04 LTS the exporting hack was not necessary, although the installation also required `sudo`. However, the `haunt build` example still fails. I will update when I know more.